# 中間テーブルを使用しアソシエーションを組んでいるがAssociationNotFoundErrorと表示されてしまう。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

現在、[【Rails6】（送信時のリロード無し！）Action CableでSlack風チャットアプリを作成-Qiita](https://qiita.com/take18k_tech/items/00cc14c0eff45073ffc7)の記事を参考にしActionCableを使用し、非同期通信のチャットルームを作成しており、チャットルームの作成はできたのですが、その作成したチャットルームをRoomのIndexで表示表示をしようとすると以下のエラーが出てきてしまいます。

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError in Rooms#index
Association named 'user' was not found on Room; perhaps you misspelled it?
Extracted source (around line #9):
              
  </div>

    <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
      <ul>
        <%= link_to room_path(room), method: :get do %>
          <li class="recommended_title">Title:  <%= room.name %><span class="share_comment_time">  <%= room.created_at.to_s(:datetime_jp) %></span></li>
```

room_userという中間テーブルを作成し、そこに以下のようにアソシエーションを組んでいます。

Room_user モデル

```
class RoomUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Roomモデル

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :room_users
  has_many :users, through: :room_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy

  def template
    ApplicationController.renderer.render partial: 'messages/message', locals: { message: self }
  end
end
```

Userモデル

```
   has_many :room_users
   has_many :rooms, through: :room_users
   has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
```

Rooms/Index.html.erb

```
<%= render "shared/header" %>

<body class="shares_body">
  <h1 class="share_title">CHAT ROOMS </h1>
  <div class="share_btn_wrapper">
    <%= link_to "◎ チャットルームを作る ◎", new_room_path, class:"share_btn" %>
  </div>

    <% @rooms.each do |room| %>
      <ul>
        <%= link_to room_path(room), method: :get do %>
          <li class="recommended_title">Title:  <%= room.name %><span class="share_comment_time">  <%= room.created_at.to_s(:datetime_jp) %></span></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <%= paginate @rooms %>

    <div class="top_page_link">
      <%= link_to "トップページに戻る", "/" %>
    </div>
</body>


<%= render "shared/footer" %>
```

Roomコントローラー

```
class RoomsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @rooms = Room.all.includes(:user).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def new
    @room = Room.new
  end

  def create
    @room = Room.new(room_params)
    if @room.save
      redirect_to rooms_path
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def show
    @messages = Message.all.includes(:user).order(:id)
    @message = current_user.messages.build
  end

  private

  def room_params
    params.require(:room).permit(:name, user_ids:[])
  end
end
```

ルームを作成するとカラムには反映されているので、あとはIndexのビューファイルに表示をさせたのですが、冒頭に申し上げたエラーが出てきてしまいます。
アソシエーションはできているのかなと思っているのですが、アソシエーション関連のエラーが出てきてしまい、他のファイルなどもチェックをしてみたのですが、どこに誤りがあるのかが分からずお力添え頂きたく質問をあげさせて頂きました。
学習も始めたばかりで拙い説明とコードではありますが、どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
コントローラー内の.includes(:user)が不要だったようです。となると、ルームにユーザが紐づいていないのかなと思うのですが、そこはもう少し自分で調べてみようと思います。